# XML not parsing completely

Tags: java, xml, json

I'm trying to extract the xml over Goodread's API, problem is the xml i've extracted is incomplete.

```
        String resultJsonStr = null;
        ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
        String xml = null;
        try {
            String str = "https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?isbn=9780755380022&key=UpH4L0IYjAXcezlfg0yT2Q";
            URL url = new URL(str);
            InputStream is = url.openStream();
            int ptr = 0;
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            while ((ptr = is.read()) != -1) {
                builder.append((char) ptr);
            }
            StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(builder);
            xml = builder.toString();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

[I'm using this xml](https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn?isbn=9780755380022&key=UpH4L0IYjAXcezlfg0yT2Q)
The code stops inside reviews_widget I believe it's reading the thing as a style, and disregarding further lines of the xml.

[inside String xml](https://wk9fqw-sn3302.files.1drv.com/y2plAtmVTxBHa3uIdb3FBcQ-yp26jxkzOKZOZ6FPPkI58gDwwt8JY5JOzO88zm71fHUQX0wOH1NNOZYT2xBAjCuJ0_3CUSYs09AGLYPyAqHWo_rbxj6cJmWEOtrC6_9Q1tLRERMgcD-hZo3se5gkLYQ6w/Capture2.PNG?psid=1)

I'm doing this in preparation for JSON conversion.

Comment: Aside from anything else, this is *not* a good way to read a text file. You're basically assuming it's ISO-8859-1, which it isn't. Most XML parsers allow you to provide an `InputStream` with the data in - that's what you should do, so that the XML parser can handle encodings.

Comment: It just stops? No error?

Comment: @JonSkeet what parsers specifically?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no errors. :/

Comment: I'm getting the whole response using your code. I'm not sure what the image you added indicates. Why do you say it stops?

Comment: I don't remember ever seeing an XML parser that didn't all for this, to be honest.

Comment: It does run actually but I want to extract the entire xml, but then this is where the xml string [ends](https://ifhpfg-sn3302.files.1drv.com/y2pxXw25lThCf-Hca1TIJU06qFOMIKl5H5UnlSQYWl-vK8E_I_6bnO2wsAGuegbbO5WU5v3tb8befiwEFmJtDofavC6LOjZpM2R0lGGoGsbf7k4aQS-h7Jv8ha3brXQ5wws_-K36pIB4_zrWSL6jU_Qag/Capture.PNG?psid=1)

Comment: Please, no links. I can't get to that link. Add all new information to your original question by editing. On my machine, the contents of the variable `xml` ends with `</GoodreadsResponse>`, which indicates it's the whole XML.